# Noob and receiving syntax error for google-search code

Tags: ruby, search, syntax

Pretty much have typed code from this example word for word, and receiving following syntax error message.  Please help!!

https://github.com/visionmedia/google-search/blob/master/examples/web.rb

My code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "google-search"

def find_item uri, query
    search = Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
        search.query = query
        search.size = :large
        search.each_response {print "."; #stdout.flush}
    end
        search.find {|item| item.uri =~ uri}
end

def rank_for query
    print "%35s " % query
    if item = find_item(/vision\-media\.ca/, query)
        puts " #%d" % (item.index +1)
    else
        puts " Not found"
    end
end

rank_for "Victoria Web Training"
rank_for "Victoria Web School"
rank_for "Victoria Web Design"
rank_for "Victoria Drupal"
rank_for "Victoria Drupal Development"
```

Error message:

```
Ruby Google Search:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
Ruby Google Search:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
Ruby Google Search:26: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've inadvertently commented out the remainder of line 9:

```
search.each_response {print "."}
```

Note that the `#` character in Ruby denotes a comment; i.e., everything on the same line to the right of the `#` *inclusive* is considered comment and is not compiled as Ruby code.

```
print 'this ' +  'is ' + 'compiled'
#=> this is compiled

print 'this' # + 'is' +  'not'
#=> this
```

Note that the bracket `{}` notation encapsulates a single executable line contained within a block. What you're trying to do, however, is to execute two commands. For this, it may be more semantically readable to use Ruby's [`block`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html) notation:

```
search.each_response do
    print '.'
    STDOUT.flush
end
```

Comment: While I didn't downvote, because you're correct, using semicolons and a single line sometimes makes more sense than breaking statements into separate lines.

Comment: I'll try both using a single line and and breaking the statement into separate lines - I'm a noob, I need the practice anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `#stdout.flush`, type `$stdout.flush`.

Answer (score -1):

The last line of the do block in `find_item` is:

```
search.each_response {print "."; #stdout.flush}
```

Where the `#` in Ruby marks the beginning of comment. You've commented out the remainder of the line, but not before opening a bracket `{`. The lack of it being closed is the source of your error.

In order for your code to be correct, you should change the `#` to `$` to access the global stdout object.

Comment: @zeantsoi Did I miss something?

Comment: No, I had accidentally made an edit to your answer when I meant to make it to mine. I've subsequently rolled back my edit.

Comment: I have two downvotes for describing the problem in the question? Do we get downvoted for being correct now? If either one of the downvoters had left a comment, as recommended when you downvote, perhaps this answer wouldn't remain so dissatisfactory.